# NextJS 13 + how to send an XML/Text response

Tags: next.js13

I'm using nextjs with app router. My task is to mimic this old express route using the nextjs API:

```js
router.post("/voice", (req, res) => {
  res.set("Content-Type", "text/xml");
  res.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

This would just send my generated XML normally.

Now my attempt in NextJS:

```
export async function POST(request: Request, response: Response) {
    return Response.json(twiml.toString());
}
```

I set up the route correctly and i'm able to post to /voice, but now I want to just send the `twiml.toString()` in text/XMLinstead of JSON. Any idea how?

Answer (score 1):

`return new Response(twiml.toString())` should be fine for your case